# Theoretical possibilities for cpu emulation built into boot-loader or kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, grub, boot-loader, qemu

Is it a crazy idea to somehow make a blend of grub and qemu in order to boot linux kernels or any kernel of any cpu type supported by qemu or the built-in cpu?

I know it might be impossible to detach the bootloader if its emulating the cpu, but maybe the work around would be to make the cpu emulation built into a linux kernel so that the boot-loader can detach. But is this kind of idea crazy and would never work or just too much work for anybody to take on?

Comment: What would be the difference with a qemu inside an initrd of a native kernel ?

Answer (score 3):

Qemu runs on top of a host operating system. A bootloader such as Grub doesn't provide enough services for Qemu. Qemu runs as an ordinary process inside the host, it needs the host kernel to perform memory management, to access filesystems, etc.

If you meant to run an OS compiled for a different processor architecture, that won't work. The virtual machine is still dependent on the host system for all hardware access. The kernel inside the virtual machine accesses the hardware emulated by Qemu, not the real hardware.

The only reason to run Qemu is if you have programs compiled for a different architecture, and this is mostly useful to test those programs without using an appropriate physical device.